# How to track distributed tasks progress

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, distributed-system

Here is my case:

1. When my server receieve a request, it will trigger distributed tasks, in my case many AWS lambda functions (the peek value could be 3000)
2. I need to track each task progress / status i.e. pending, running, success, error
3. My server could have many replicas
4. I still want to know about the task progress / status even if any of my server replica down

My current design:

1. I choose AWS S3 as my helper
2. When a task start to execute, it will create marker file in a special folder on S3 e.g. *running* folder
3. When the task fail or success, it will move the marker file from *running* folder to *fail* folder or *success* folder
4. I check the marker files on S3 to check the progress of the tasks.

The problems:

1. There is a limit for AWS S3 concurrent access
2. My case is likely to exceed the limit some day

Attempt Solutions:

1. I had tried my best to reduce the number of request to S3
2. I don't want to track the progress by storing data in my DB because my DB has already been under heavy workload.

To be honest, it is kind of wierd that using marker files on S3 to track progress of the tasks. However, it worked before.

Is there any recommendations ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect application of persistent event queueing, specifically Kinesis.  As each Lambda starts it generates a “starting” event on Kinesis.  When it succeeds or fails, it generates the appropriate event.  You could even create progress events along the way if you want to see how far they have gotten.

Your server can then monitor the number of starting events against ending events (success or failure) until these two numbers are equal.  It can query the error events to see which processes failed and why.  All servers can query the same events without disrupting each other, and any server can go down and recover without losing data.

Make sure to put an Origination Key on events that are supposed to be grouped together so they don't get mixed up with a subsequent event.  Also, each Lambda should be given its own key so you can trace progress per Lambda.  Guids are perfect for this.

Comment: Hi,  I have one question about your solution.
If my servers restart, how could I trace progress of the previous tasks ? 
What I understand is that after the persistent event queue deliever an event successfully, it will remove it, so I can not query the same event any more.

Comment: Regular queues (RabbitMQ, AWS SQS, or Azure Queue Service) will remove messages once they are confirmed to have been processed.  Durable queues (Kafka, AWS Kinesis, or Azure Event Hub) maintain the messages for a user-defined period.  Default for Kinesis is 7 days, but it can be extended for an additional fee.  All 3 of these services allow retrieving unread messages, or read and unread message since a point in time.  This allows re-processing of messages if necessary, or multiple servers processing the same message.

Comment: BTW, what I call "durable queues" are more formally known as Streaming Data systems.  I should not have used the term "durable queue" because it means something different when talking about queuing systems.