# AWS SQS: How to check if several messages were processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Let's image the following situation:

I send the messages `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, and once these messages are processed, I need to send new message `MFinal`, because it can be processed only after previous messages.

**FIFO Queue** doesn't work for me because I want the messages `M1`, `M2` and `M3` to be processed in parallel (I have multiple consumers).

Is it possible to watch these messages somehow?

Comment: How did it go? The issue is still unclear?

Comment: @Marcin we ended up using FIFO queue, because there were other issues with this approach.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51057322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to watch these messages somehow?

Yes, but you need **custom solution** for that. Usually your consumers of the messages would store the status of the message processing in some database (e.g. DynamoDB). Once all messages have been written to the database, then you would check for that and send final notification to the producer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was thinking about something like that as well, but I am not sure I understand how to check if the processing is completed. One way would be to check the DB after each message is processed, but it will have a big performance impact when I'd have big amount of messages.

Comment: @VyacheslavPalamar It depends on your use-case. Does it have to be real-time check? The four msgs can't be in FIFO, but maybe you can use FIFO for storing mgs processing completion info? Then the FIFO is read other service which monitors full completion.

Answer (score 2):

> I send the messages M1, M2, M3, and once these messages are processed, I need to send new message MFinal, because it can be processed only after previous messages.

**assuming you can approx when your m1,m2,m3 will be processed**, then you can use **delay queues** to delay a message

> Delay queues let you postpone the delivery of new messages to a queue for a number of seconds, for example, when your consumer application needs additional time to process messages. If you create a delay queue, any messages that you send to the queue remain invisible to consumers for the duration of the delay period. The default (minimum) delay for a queue is 0 seconds. The maximum is 15 minutes

For more https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to predict when all the messages will be processed because the amount of consumers may vary.

Comment: if thats the case, use a deal letter queue, which makes sure that within the time out period and threshold value set by you, your message is processed , if not then send it to dead letter queue, so in other words your message is either processed or not in the queue