# Track completion status of batch of tasks in AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I have queue where I publish multiple batches of tasks to same queue. Each batch is associated with a unique identifier. Is there a way to track completion status of the batch? I can think of attaching message group ID to each message of the batch but I couldn't find a way to know if all messages of a particular batch got consumed or not?
If SQS doesn't support this, is there any other way to track completion of the batch?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51057322